# Knockout.js ko.observableArray() not working as espected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I am not sure why this doesn't work can anyone help?

I have this simple object array:

```
     myItems: [
       {value: 0, text: 'a'},
       {value: 1, text: 'b'},
       {value: 2, text: 'c'}
     ],


allItems: ko.observableArray(this.myItems),

console.log(this.allItems()); THIS DOES NOT WORK???
```

the above does not Work ?

Now the bellow is just the myItems array hardcoded:

```
allItems: ko.observableArray([
       {value: 0, text: 'a'},
       {value: 1, text: 'b'},
       {value: 2, text: 'c'}
     ]),

console.log(this.allItems()); //THIS NOW WORKS
```

What is the difference as I don't see any when I log both:

```
console.log('this is al allItems: '+this.allItems())
console.log('this is my myItems: '+myItems());
this is al allItems: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
this is my myItems: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Any help Please!Appreciate.

Comment: you are accessing variable `myItems` using `this` keyword which is wrong . you should access function properties using `this` & variables directly as is http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/47916/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like while initializing the object you are assigning the value of it's one of the key to the other key. in your given snippet, `this` is referring to the global object where the `myItems` key is not present and returning `undefined`.
Try doing `var a = {b: 1, c: this.b}` in your browser. this will return `{ b: 1, c: undefined }`.

But my question is, why you want to keep `myItems` separately and don't want to pass its value directly to the `ko.observableArray` function? 
because later you will only want to deal with `allItems` as it is observable, not `myItems`.

Comment: ajax request the response data that will be : [
       {value: 0, text: 'a'},
       {value: 1, text: 'b'},
       {value: 2, text: 'c'}
     ];

this.myItems = response;
allItems: ko.observableArray(this.myItems)

Comment: If your response is not undefined, you should be able to do `ko.observableArray(response)`

Comment: it doesn't work that's why I create hard coded data to see the issue. But I found that .push work this.allItems.push({....}) .

Comment: @JulianoVargas as its a array you don't need to push check my comment above.

Comment: @super cool this.myItems  is the response from ajax and an array with object and it does not work by doing allItems: ko.observableArray(this.myItems) thank's for your effort.